# Debugging types with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

Consider the following code:

```
template<class T>
void foo()
{
    T x;
}
```

How can I find the type of x while debugging? Adding `typeid(x).name()` is invalid in the watch list.

How do people generally debug template metaprogramming?

Comment: `std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a gcc extension

Comment: If you depend on `std::cout`, you might as well use `std::cout << typeid(x).name()`. That's missing the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `x` itself to the watch list. The third column of the watch window will list the actual type of `x`, i.e. the `T` used to instantiate `foo<T>`

Comment: Wow! I did not see that column! It was all the way off my screen, I had to horizontally scroll. New feature discovered.

Comment: Sike! The type column is blank... https://i.imgur.com/n64489K.png

Comment: @superdeveloper: Well, the variable `x` has to exist, which means you need to hit a breakpoint somewhere where `x` is in scope. If no instance of `foo` is executing, no `x` exists.

Comment: I was able to deduce the type by looking at the assembly. For anyone curious, it’s Alt+8. I’ll still leave this answer accepted. As for why the type column was empty, I have no idea - I was able to see the value fine.